# Equivalent of a sequence defined as induction formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined as
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n+1} \text{ with } a_0=a_1=1
$$
I've shown that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n-k+1}{k!}\left(-1\right)^k
$$
How can I show, rigorously, that
$$
a_n \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{n}{e} \ ?
$$
I know that if a series $\sum_{n \geq 0}b_n$ diverges and that $b_n \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}c_n$ then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_k \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k
$$
can I use this result to prove it ?

Comment: Did you find $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n-k+1}{k!}\left(-1\right)^k$ by yourself or were you asked to verify it ?

Comment: I found it by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n-k+1}{k!}\left(-1\right)^k = n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} - \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k-1}{k!}(-1)^k$$

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ converges to  $e^{-1}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k-1}{k!}(-1)^k$ converges absolutely to some irrelevant value.

Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n-k+1}{k!}\left(-1\right)^k =n(e^{-1}+o(1))+O(1)=ne^{-1} +o(n)$.

Comment: Ah yeah it was not that hard, thank you